# Plot logit models estimates with interaction effects

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I estimated a logit model looking like this:

`glm(dependent_variable ~ independent_variable1*independent_variable2 + independent_variable3 + independent_variable4,data = mydata, family = "binomial")`

Now I want to plot the impact of the "independent_variable1" on the dependent varibale and the difference the interaction term makes. Solutions I found so far were only focused on the interaction term, however I ant to visualize the difference the interaction term makes. Since my interaction variable is continuous (ranging from 0 to -11) it would be usefull to only plot the interaction for certain values like 0, -5, -10.

Comment: have a look at [`sjPlot`](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/),

Comment: Look into the packages effects and ggeffects for calculating and plotting model effects.

Comment: I've updated my answer to your similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71387491/17303805) to include a logit model.