# Marginal effects/predictions at representative values (with other values at observed)

Tags: r, stata, predict, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

I have been looking around for a way to calculate marginal effects/predictions at specific values in R, while the remaining variables are kept as observed. I believe this is the default in Stata (for example, when using `margins, at(age=(30 35 40 45 50))` (see [Stata manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjnhNfv2qb7AhVwxosKHYl6BrcQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stata.com%2Fmanuals%2Frmargins.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1basSH0bIuspk2DGHHg-u-)).

From what I can tell, `marginaleffects` and `ggeffects` automatically sets the other variables to the mean. Is there a good way to achieve this (preferably using the above packages)?

Comment: My answer in this thread shows how to specify values for marginal effects in ggeffects: [Pick a point approach: plotting interaction effects in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387130/pick-a-point-approach-plotting-interaction-effects-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with the `marginaleffects` package. Please refer
to the documentation for details. In particular, note that the `at`
notation in `Stata` replicates the *full* dataset several times for each
value of the specified variable, and then averages. This is equivalent
to using the `datagridcf()` function in `marginaleffects` to create
“counter-factual” datasets, and the `by` argument to marginalize. You
may also find those two vignettes useful:

1. [Marginal Effects
   Vignette](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/marginaleffects.html)
2. [Detailed comparison between `marginaleffects` and
   `Stata`](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#stata)

```r
library(marginaleffects)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + am, data = mtcars)

predictions(mod, newdata = datagridcf(hp = c(110, 120, 130)), by = "hp")

          type  hp predicted std.error statistic p.value conf.low conf.high
    1 response 110  22.25107 0.5895479  37.74260       0 21.09558  23.40656
    2 response 120  21.66219 0.5553795  39.00431       0 20.57367  22.75072
    3 response 130  21.07332 0.5307275  39.70647       0 20.03311  22.11352

marginaleffects(mod, newdata = datagridcf(hp = c(110, 120, 130)), by = "hp")

          type term    contrast       dydx   std.error statistic      p.value
    1 response   hp mean(dY/dX) -0.0588878 0.007856747 -7.495189 6.620280e-14
    2 response   hp mean(dY/dX) -0.0588878 0.007856747 -7.495189 6.620280e-14
    3 response   hp mean(dY/dX) -0.0588878 0.007856745 -7.495191 6.620172e-14
    4 response   am mean(dY/dX)  5.2770853 1.079540509  4.888270 1.017260e-06
    5 response   am mean(dY/dX)  5.2770853 1.079540509  4.888270 1.017260e-06
    6 response   am mean(dY/dX)  5.2770853 1.079540509  4.888270 1.017260e-06
         conf.low   conf.high predicted predicted_hi predicted_lo  hp
    1 -0.07428674 -0.04348886  25.38434     25.38267     25.38434 110
    2 -0.07428674 -0.04348886  24.79546     24.79380     24.79546 120
    3 -0.07428674 -0.04348887  24.20658     24.20492     24.20658 130
    4  3.16122479  7.39294583  25.38434     25.38487     25.38434 110
    5  3.16122479  7.39294583  24.79546     24.79599     24.79546 120
    6  3.16122479  7.39294583  24.20658     24.20711     24.20658 130
```